# Python - Passar parâmetro ao invés de módulos na declaração FROM

Tags: python

Boa tarde pessoal.

Estou com um dilema ao fazer a declaração do FROM .. import para importar os módulos, como segue abaixo:

- Para essa utilidade, não quero e não posso passar a declaração FROM..import no início do script, preciso chamar diretamente na função. Aqui tem um problema, pois é uma função um tanto quanto genérica, era para ser pelo menos.
  É uma função que dependendo da opção que o usuário escolher irá necessitar de um módulo diferente, então minha ideia é passar os módulos por variável e usar essas variáveis na declaração do FROM..import como segue abaixo:

tanto o nome dos diretório dos módulos quanto o nome da classe é teste, por exemplo.

```
var_concorrente = teste
from + var_concorrente import var_concorrente
```

o problema é que desse jeito não funciona.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Não quero fazer um script muito grande e será se não tiver jeito, caso não ache uma solução para isso.

Deixa eu tentar melhorar minha questão.

O from normal seria assim:

from source.netspeed.netspeed import Netspeed

O source é o nome do diretório que contem todos os modulos.

O primeiro netspeed é o diretório do cliente

O segundo netspeed é o nome do modulo

Já o Netspeed é o nome da classe dentro no modulo netspeed

tenho que passar tudo isso por parametro, tipo assim:

cliente = "netspeed" from_estructure = "source."+cliente+"."+cliente

declarar o from usando essas variáveis:

from from_estructure import cliente.capitalize()

Grato a todos.

Comment: Consegue dar um exemplo concreto do que quer fazer? Por exemplo, mostrando pelo menos dois módulos diferentes que seriam importados pela função, mostrar qual é a ideia dessa função e quais seriam as chamadas para cada módulo?

Comment: Deixa eu tentar melhorar minha questão.

O from normal seria assim:

from source.netspeed.netspeed import Netspeed

O source é o nome do diretório que contem todos os modulos.

O primeiro netspeed é o diretório do cliente

O segundo netspeed é o nome do modulo

Já o Netspeed é o nome da classe dentro no modulo netspeed

tenho que passar tudo isso por parametro, tipo assim:

cliente = "netspeed"
from_estructure = "source."+cliente+"."+cliente

declarar o from usando essas variáveis:

from from_estructure import cliente.capitalize()

Comment: O nome do módulo **sempre** é igual ao nome do diretório do cliente? E o nome da classe, será sempre `Netspeed`, independente do cliente?

Comment: O nome do módulo sempre será o nome do cliente com caixa baixa, e a Classe será sempre o nome do modulo com primeira letra caixa alta.

Comment: Todas as classes que poderão ser importadas possuem o mesmo contrato? Isto é, será garantido que os métodos e atributos que você utilizará na função existem em todas as classes possíveis?

Comment: Não. Várias funções não iguais, mas cada cliente tem uma função específica, por isso separei em módulos. Caso contrário usaria todas no mesmo módulo, creio eu.

Comment: Então depois que importar a classe como saberá quais métodos você pode utilizar dela? Isso está parecendo um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/5878), em que você tenta implementar algo que acha que é solução, mas não é.

Comment: Por que isso será chamado via menu criado para isso.
eu tenho um menu para, exemplo, imprimir um somatório, então quando o cliente escolher esse menu, será essas informações passadas pelo parâmetro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui resolver a questão acima do modo abaixo:

```
import_module = str("source." + concurrent + "." + concurrent)
import_class = concurrent.capitalize()
from_estructure = __import__(import_module, fromlist=import_class)
```

Comment: Mas isso é basicamente o que o jsbueno respondeu, não?

Comment: faltou o uso do "fromlist=". sem ele não certo.

Comment: E o `getattr` não resolve este problema?

Comment: Então, agradeço as colocações aqui.
Avaliando melhor a documentação e como funciona o __import__ e posteriormente o getattr conseguir fazer com ele tb.

Mais uma vez agradeço

Answer (score 1):

É possível importar um módulo com o nome em uma string, em vez de digitado diretamente no código, com a função built-in `__import__`. O comando import realmente exige que o nome a ser importado steja definido.

A função `__import__` não tem uma opção de  `from`, em vez dela, pode se fazer uma atribuição simples. Se o nome do que você quer importar dentro do módulo também for variável, você pode usar o `getattr`

```
def minha_funcao(nome_modulo, nome_objeto):
    modulo = __import__(nome_modulo)
    objeto = getattr(modulo, nome_objeto)

    ...
```

Comment: Ainda não estou a esse nível de entendimento. Deixa eu continuar meu questionamento baseado nessa sua sugestão.
E se a classe estiver na seguinte estrutura:

diretório "source"
Dentro de "Source" tenho o diretório "Netspeed"

Comment: `__import__("source.Netspeed")`

Comment: (por favor, maiúsculas e minusculas tem que ser determinísticos "source" e "Source" são coisas diferentes. )

Comment: Então, entendo a questão de ser case sensitive. Agradeço o toque.
Estou tentando assim: 

concurrent = self.config.converter
var_modulo = str("source."+concurrent+"."+concurrent)

mas não está dando certo, ele só encontra a "source".

como fazer?